# unicorn syncing same sitecore items again and again

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-unicorn

We are using unicorn 3.2.0 for sitecore 8.1 update 3.

I noticed where ever i did a sync from unicorn.aspx some items repeatedly modified even though they are unmodified.

```
UPM sync complete: 1740 items evaluated, 67 items modified (0 added, 67 updated, 0 recycled) in 9816ms (~5.6ms/item).
```

These 67 items are not modified. This keeps happening only to these set of items.

when i checked the log files i found:

```
 14480 18:13:13 INFO  [Unicorn]: > Field Key - Reset to standard value
 14480 18:13:13 INFO  [Unicorn]: * [U] Key
 14480 18:13:13 INFO  [Unicorn]: * [U] Value
```

I don't understand why these fields are reset to standard value? These two fields key and value are shared fields.

Let me know if u need more info

Comment: Do you have two config files pointing to the same /serialization folder? This happened to me when I copied a config file and forgot to change the path.

Comment: @dnstommy what do u mean by two config files? if u mean by sitecore.config or unicorn.configs.default.config, No they are no duplicates for those.

Comment: Its the target data store in your config. Do you have one unicorn config for all items or several? <targetDataStore physicalRootPath="$(sourceFolder)\Feature\Blog\serialization" type="Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore, Rainbow" useDataCache="false" singleInstance="true" />

Comment: Only one config file. its in app_config\include\unicorn\unicorn.config

Comment: I wonder if this is your answer. https://github.com/kamsar/Rainbow/blob/a7df6a7a7c18badef715d65c916845f22266e5ba/src/Rainbow.Storage.Sc/Deserialization/DefaultDeserializer.cs#L434

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Unicorn 4.0.4. A 4.0.4-pre1 release is available on NuGet.

More information here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9671/unicorn-always-serializes-items-which-have-fallback-enabled